# Remove processed source files after AWS Datapipeline completes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

A third party sends me a daily upload of log files into an S3 bucket.  I'm attempting to use DataPipeline to transform them into a slightly different format with awk, place the new files back on S3, then move the original files aside so that I don't end up processing the same ones again tomorrow.

Is there a clean way of doing this?  Currently my shell command looks something like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu -o pipefail

aws s3 cp s3://example/processor/transform.awk /tmp/transform.awk

for f in "${INPUT1_STAGING_DIR}"/*; do
  basename=${f//+(*\/|.*)}
  unzip -p "$f" | awk -f /tmp/transform.awk | gzip > ${OUTPUT1_STAGING_DIR}/$basename.tsv.gz
done
```

I could use the aws cli tool to move the source file aside on each iteration of the loop, but that seems flakey - if my loop dies halfway through processing, those earlier files are going to get lost.

Answer (score 0):

Few possible solutions:

1. Create a trigger on your s3 bucket.. Whenever any object added to the bucket --> invoke lambda function which can be a python script which performs transformation --> copies back to another bucket. Now, on this other bucket again lambda function is invoked which deletes file from first bucket.
2. I personally feel; what you have achieved is good enough..All you need is exception handling in the shell script and delete the file ( never loose data ) ONLY when output file is successfully created ( probably u can check the size of output file also )

Comment: With (2), I worry that I'm relying on OUTPUT1_STAGING_DIR to sync my files back to S3 at the end of the run, and so might lose them if my pipeline dies halfway through.   Or is OUTPUT1_STAGING_DIR an actual S3 mount  and anything written there is synchronously available in the destination S3 bucket?